# simultaneous approximation of functions and their derivatives in L^2(R)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $f$ is absolutely continuous on every bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f'\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Then there is a sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $C_c^{(1)}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ and $f_n'\rightarrow f'$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

How to construct that sequence? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you studied mollifiers? If you have, then you should be able to show that $\eta_{\epsilon}\star f$ converges to $f$ in $L^2$ and its first derivative converges to $f'$ in $L^2$.

Comment: There is also  the issue of truncation to make the $f_n$ have compact support.

Comment: combine @TrialAndError and Uhmberto P 's ideas, I get this. First,give $f$ a trunction by interval $[-n,n]$ we get $f_n$, choose n sufficient large such that $||f-f_n||$ and $||f'-f_n'||$ small. Secondly, choose a mollifer  $\eta$ with compact support to mollify $f_n$ and get a smooth function $\eta_{\epsilon}\star f$ with compact support . When $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, one can make $|| \eta_{\epsilon}\star f - f_n ||$ and $|| \eta_{\epsilon}\star f' - f_n'|| $ sufficient small.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly: Suppose first $f$ itself has compact support, say in $[-a,a].$ Note that this implies $\int_{-a}^a f' = 0.$ Let $\epsilon>0.$ Then we can choose $g\in C_c(-a,a)$ such that $\int_{-a}^a g = 0, \int_{-a}^a|g-f'|^2 < \epsilon.$ Define $G(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x g.$ Then $G \in C^1(\mathbb R)$ with support in $[-a,a].$ Verify that

$$ \int_{-a}^a |G-f|^2 \le 4a^2\epsilon.$$

This shows the result is true if $f$ has compact support. For the general $f$, note that if $\varphi \in C^1_c,$ then $f\varphi$ has compact support and satisfies the same hypotheses as does $f.$ So all we need to do is show that there is such a $\varphi$ with $\int_{\mathbb R}|f-f\varphi|^2,\int_{\mathbb R}|f'-(f\varphi)'|^2$ as small as we like.

Comment: How to find a $\varphi$ satisfies this ?

Comment: Given an interval $[-a,a],$ there exists $\varphi \in C_c^\infty$ such that $ \varphi = 1 $ in $[-a,a],$ $0\le \varphi \le 1,$$ |\varphi '|\le 1.$ Given $f$ choose an interval $[-a,a]$ such that $\int_{|x|>a}|f|^2, \int_{|x|>a}|f'|^2$ are small, then use the $\varphi$ above.

Comment: $f\varphi$ may not belong to $C_c^{(1)}(\mathbb{R})$,since $f'$ may not be continuous

Comment: But $f\varphi$ has compact support as in the first paragraph.